# Primefaces Hide Dialog When File Uploads

Tags: primefaces

The primefaces fileUpload component has an update attribute but I can't do a update="dialog.show()";  Anyone know how to hide a dilog when the file upload is complete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2.2.1 doesn't have it but new fileupload of PrimeFaces 3.0 has oncomplete attribute you can use.